# HEX to Threejs rgb conversion with THREE.MeshPhongMaterial not working

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using below js code to change color of a part in 3D model

```
document.getElementById("custom_color").onchange = function() {
    var custom_color = $("#custom_color").val().split('#').join("0x");
    console.log(custom_color);
    const color = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: custom_color, shininess: 10 });
    console.log(color);
    var name = $(".--is-active").data("option");
    initColor(speaker,name,color);
  }
```

First console.log(custom_color) giving result

```
0xd04343
```

Second console.log(color) giving as

```
color object as 
b: 1
g: 1
r: 1
```

I am unable to understand why **THREE.MeshPhongMaterial** not converting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you pass string "0xd04343" instead of a real hex `0xd04343`. If you want to pass a string, then leave it as is with `#` and pass it into `color` parameter: "#d04343". That format of string in CSS-style is valid for color.

The [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Color) say:

*It can be a CSS-style string. For example:*

*'rgb(250, 0,0)'*

*'rgb(100%,0%,0%)'*

*'hsl(0, 100%, 50%)'*

*'#ff0000'*

*'#f00'*

*'red'*